# How Can You Get Into Apples UEFI setup And Can It Even Be Accessed?

Tags: boot, uefi, firmware

I was wondering if I can access the UEFI setup on the apple motherboard so I can change the boot order. I know you can hold the option key on start up but I wanted to do it through the UEFI anyways.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - rather than ask about a way to achieve your potential workaround, why not ask for a solution to the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Apple's EFI doesn't include a setup utility like those common on PCs. You can, though, set the boot order inside your OS(es) of choice:

- In OS X, you'd use the Startup Disk item in System Preferences.
- In Linux, you can use the `efibootmgr` tool.
- In Windows, you'd use `bcdedit` or the third-party [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) tool.
- In an EFI shell, you can use the `bcfg` command.

These tools vary in their features and capabilities. Startup Disk in OS X is the most limited, but of course it was designed for Macs and so is likely to be the safest to use. The other tools are designed for more standard EFIs, but they *should* work on Macs. (I've used `efibootmgr` on Macs, but not the other tools.)

Also, note that all of these tools rely on EFI features that are accessible only if you boot in EFI mode. If you boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode (as is common for Windows, especially Windows 7 and earlier), you won't be able to access EFI variables and so will not be able to adjust the boot order.